# Jquery: go to anchor. Content id hidden

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code to make a "go to anchor" using jquery. **It works** but.... the problem is that the content is hidden for a fixed element (the Header of my site). This header has a height:109px

**Then my question is:** Can I modify this code to add or subtract these 109px to the position of the anchor ?

code:

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}

$("#go_to_image1").click(function() {
   scrollToAnchor('image1');
});
```

HTML

```
<a name="image1"></a>
<h6 id="go_to_image1">Ver Imagen 1</h6>
```

Comment: Could you please post jsfiddle?

Comment: DO you want anchor below 109px right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add or subtract any number inside your `.animate` function.

You can use a hardcoded value (like I did in the example) or you can also get the actual size of an element and then add/subtract this value until you have the exact position you need to scroll to.

```js
function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
    
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top - 109},'slow');
}

$("#go_to_image1").click(function() {
   scrollToAnchor('image1');
});
```

```css
.target {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 10px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h6 id="go_to_image1">Ver Imagen 1</h6>

<div style="height: 200vh">
</div>
<a name="image1" href="" class="target"></a>
<div style="height: 200vh">
</div>
```